# Reference on relation between SFTs and Wang-tiles

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, tiling, symbolic-dynamics

I've been looking at several papers which allude to a relation between SFTs. Namely, given an SFT $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ with allowed patches $\mathcal{F}$, we can associate a set of domino\Wang tiles $T_{\mathcal{F}}$ defined by $\mathcal{F}$. The question of whether there is a periodic configuration, an $\omega\in \Omega$ such that $\vert \text{orbit}_{\mathbb{Z}^2}(\omega)\vert<\infty$, can be determined by studying the domino problem for $T_{\mathcal{F}}$.
Alternatively, given a set of Wang\domino $T$, we can choose an alphabet $ \mathcal{A}$ and get an SFT $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ encoding the domino\wang problem of $T$.

Is there a good reference for this sort of relation? I've mainly found this topic discussed shortly in the prelimnaries of several papers. For example,

- [A SELF-SIMILAR APERIODIC SET OF 19 WANG TILES](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03265.pdf) in section 2.
- [On the domino problem of the Baumslag-Solitar groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439752100517X) in section 2.2.
- [Multi-Dimensional Symbolic Dynamical Systems](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-0165-3_3), in section 3.

I was wondering if there is a good reference dealing with this relation\encoding of Wang tiles and SFTs. All these papers deal with this shortly, but I assumed that there might be a reference dealing with this relation more thoroughly, which I was not able to find.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to see an explicit spelling out of the procedure for going from a set of Wang tiles to a set of forbidden patches and vice versa? The procedure in one direction is rather simple. From a set of Wang tiles, just forbid all two-tile patches whose neighbouring edges have different colours. From a set of forbidden patches, the process is a little more involved and, in general you will need a much larger set of colours than the size of the alphabet you started with, but the resulting tile-sets will be MLD. I'm not sure of a good reference for the harder direction.

Comment: @DanRust I was interested in going from symbolic SFTs to Wang tiles and back via these relations, but I thought that some information might be distorted along the way. Since this correspondence\relation seems to be referenced in plenty of places, I thought some people might have already checked what happens in the process.

Comment: So would you be happy with someone spelling out the construction, or do you really want a reference? Because I could write the construction fairly quickly, but wouldn't know a good (published) place to see it written down.

Comment: @DanRust I would prefer a reference if one exists, but I would be glad to finally see the correspondence explicitly. I take into account that perhaps no one bothered to write such a reference so far.

Comment: This result is proved in the masters thesis of Shahar Mozes - https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02793412

Comment: @Asaf It seems that Mozes makes a relation between SFTs and a different set of square tiles with corresponding adjacency relations, rather than being Wang tiles. Specifically the construction seems to yield much more varied and complicated tiles. Is the result the construction described in section 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a good reference at hand but I can explain the procedure. I'll use a quadruple to denote a Wang tile $T = (N,E,S,W)$ referring to the North, East, South and West edges of a tile respectively.

**Easy direction:** Given a set of Wang tiles $\{T_1, \ldots, T_k\}$, let $B_h$ be the set of pairs $(T_i,T_j)$ such that $T_i(E) \neq T_j(W)$ and let $B_v$ be the set of pairs $(T_i,T_j)$ such that $T_i(S) \neq T_j(N)$. Now let $\mathcal{F}_h$ be the patch of tiles with $T_j$ to the right of $T_i$, where $(T_i, T_j) \in B_h$ and let $\mathcal{F}_v$ be the patch of tiles with $T_j$ below $T_i$, where $(T_i,T_j) \in B_v$. We may now take our set of forbidden patches $\mathcal{F}$ to be given by $\mathcal{F}_h \cup \mathcal{F}_v$.

**Harder direction:** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be our alphabet. Given a set of forbidden patches $\mathcal{F} = \{P_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq k\}$, without loss of generality, we may assume that each of the patches is supported on an $n \times n$ square (as otherwise, just take all possible extensions of the patches to an $n \times n$ square such that $n$ is big enough to contain all the patches). Now, let $\mathcal{L}^{n,n}$ be the set of legal $n \times n$ patches. That is, $\mathcal{L}^{n,n} = \mathcal{A}^{n,n}\setminus \mathcal{F}$. Let $P_N$ be the patch one gets by deleting the northern-most row of $P$. Similarly for $P_E$, $P_S$ and $P_W$ for their respective rows/columns.

For every $P \in \mathcal{L}^{n,n}$, we define a Wang tile $T_P$ by

$$T_P(N) = (P_S, P_W, P_N, P_E).$$

So, the northern edge of $T_P$ contains all of the information of the patch $P$ except for the southern-most row, etc.

It's not too hard to see that two Wang tiles $T_P$ and $T_Q$ can only be placed next to each other if their corresponding North-South or East-West pair are identical, which is the same as saying that the patches $P$ and $Q$ overlap in a legal way.

There is now a simple local rule that takes one from a tiling with the Wang tiles $T_P$, $P \in \mathcal{L}^{n,n}$ to an element of the original SFT $X_{\mathcal{F}}$ whereby one just needs to rebuild the original patch $P$ from $T_P$ (which one can do using the labels of each of the edges) and then outputs the central element of $P$ (or round down if $n$ is even).